# Hibernate JPA Inheritance strange behavior

Tags: inheritance, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have two tables. Employee and User.

Employee is annotated with Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
User is annotated with @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "super_id")

Everything is fine if i use the User entity.

When i want to load Employee instance hibernate raised "Column *clazz not found" with SQL query. As a workaround i tried injecting fake column like "0 as clazz*" but is raised duplicate column error. Anyway, If i use HQL query like "from **Employee** where id=1" it loads **User** instance by id=1.

Since Employee entity is not an abstract class, i hope hibernate will load it as Employee instance.

To brief my case in details; There are many employees in my customer and some of them can use system as user and some of them can not. And also i have a third table named Managers which extends Employee entity too. Same person can be an Employee, a User and a Manager with JUST ONE ID.

In java inheritance that is possible and so easy but why not in JPA? Am i using wrong inheritance strategy? Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.